# Refresh Pivot Table Date

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need to modify the following code to refresh pivot table and change the date filter, every end of month i have a new item in my date filter for example this month is 20190531 the previous item is 20190430 i need to deselect 20190430 and select 20190531 the next month i want the same situation but i have deselect 20190531 and select the new item 20190630...I need to have this dynamic not to change manually every month

```
Sub PivotBraunRefresh()

    Sheets("Report-Inv-Actual").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Dt")
        .PivotItems("20190430").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("20190531").Visible = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you researched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build a string with the current month's last day,
check, if such a `PivotItem` exists,
set its visibility to true (as at least 1 pivotitem always has to be visible)
and then loop over all other pivotitems and switch them invisible:

```
Sub PivotBraunRefresh()
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim strMonthEnd As String

    ' last day of current month as string
    strMonthEnd = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1) - 1, "YYYYMMDD")

    ' refresh pivottable
    Sheets("Report-Inv-Actual").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

    With Sheets("Report-Inv-Actual").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Dt")
        On Error Resume Next
        ' check, if pivotfield exists
        Set pi = .PivotItems(strMonthEnd)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not pi Is Nothing Then
            pi.Visible = True
            For Each pi In .PivotItems
                If pi.Name <> strMonthEnd Then pi.Visible = False
            Next pi
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to automate it further, you might place it within your `Workbook_Open()` event routine.

Comment: Run Time Error 1004 'Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class'

Comment: i change PageFields("Dt" with PivotFields("Dt") i dint get the error but nothing happens i have the pivot checked with the 20190430 and i expect to deselect this and check 20190531

Comment: I edited my answer, as I erroneously thought, the `PivotField` was used as filter field. If it works fine for you, please mark it as answer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: the code run no error and no job my code from recorder use .PivotItems("20190430").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("20190531").Visible = True

Comment: Now I changed it to the previous month's end.

Comment: Asger can i ask for your help again?

Comment: Give it a try :)